# Calling C function from Python - undefined symbol error

Tags: python, c, gcc, ctypes

I am trying to call a C function from the Galil gclib from Python.  I am getting an undefined symbol OSError in Python so suspect a problem with my gcc command.  Especially since I don't understand all the arguments to gcc.

This is my file gtest.c

```
#include "gclibo.h" //by including the open-source header, all other headers are pulled in.                                                              

GReturn test()
{
    GReturn rc;
    char buf[1024]; //traffic buffer                                                                                                                 

    GCon g; //var used to refer to a unique connection                                                                                               

    rc = GOpen("192.168.0.174 -d", &g); //Open a connection to Galil, store the identifier in g.                                                     
    printf("rc: %d\n", (int) rc);

    rc = GInfo(g, buf, sizeof(buf));        
    printf("rc: %d\n", (int) rc);
    printf("info: %s\n", buf); //Print the connection info                                                                                           

    rc = GClose(g); //Don't forget to close!                                                                                                         

    return rc;
}
```

I compiled it with:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,gtest -o gtest.so -fPIC gtest.c
```

In Python 2.7, I get:

```
In [1]: import ctypes
In [2]: gtest = ctypes.CDLL('/home/mitch/wt1/gtest.so')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-008ab6422af2> in <module>()
----> 1 gtest = ctypes.CDLL('/home/mitch/wt1/gtest.so')

/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.pyc in __init__(self, name, mode, handle,     use_errno, use_last_error)
    363 
    364         if handle is None:
--> 365             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    366         else:
    367             self._handle = handle

OSError: /home/mitch/wt1/gtest.so: undefined symbol: GInfo
```

Tried:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,gtest -o gtest.so -lgclib -lgclibo -fPIC gtest.c
```

which succeeds and then:

```
$ ldd gtest.so

  linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd076eb000)
  libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8284d7b000)
  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8285342000)
```

Comment: You need to link with the libraries. According to the [examples](http://www.galil.com/sw/pub/all/doc/gclib/html/md_gcc.html), use `-lgclib -lgclibo`.

Comment: I tried: gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,gtest -o gtest.so -lgclib -lgclibo -fPIC gtest.c but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Does gcc succeed, or do you get an ld error? If it succeeds, edit your question to add the output from `ldd gtest.so`.

Comment: I just noticed that you have the wrong link order. It should be `gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,gtest -o gtest.so gtest.c -lgclib -lgclibo`.

Comment: Also with the right order, -lgclib and -lgclibo aren't needed.

Comment: How else would gtest.so reference the dependencies in the ELF header if you don't tell the linker? Check `readelf -d gtest.so`. You should see libgclib.so and libgclibo.so referenced as `(NEEDED)`. I'd check, but I don't have the library installed.

Comment: If the gcc includes -lgclib and -lgclibo, then libgclib.so.0 libgclibo.so.0 and libc.so.6 are all (NEEDED).  If -lgclib and -lgclibo aren't included, then only libc.so.6 is listed as (NEEDED).

Comment: If libgclib.so.0 and libgclibo.so.0 aren't `NEEDED` in the .so header, then  the runtime linker won't load them, and you'll end up back where you started with undefined symbols.

Comment: Yes.  In order to see it fail, I needed to exit Python and start it again.  Which is a little strange because if I compile without the libgclib's, go into Python, receive the undefined symbol error, recompile from a different process with the libgclib's, and try CDLL again, the Python call works fine without needing to exit Python.

Comment: Since the shared libraries are already loaded in the process, the runtime linker finds the required symbols. That's not the case when you restart Python, unless you manually pre-load the dependencies. In the second scenario, the first attempt to load the library fails, but it doesn't leave the process in a broken state. Thus the second attempt using a new build, which declares the required dependencies, works as expected.